# HELP A synthetic geometry problem involving the inscribed circle of a triangle

Tags: triangles, circles, angle

**PROBLEM:**

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $BC>AB$. We denote by $D,E,F$ the contact points of the inscribed circle with $BC,CA,AB$ and with $I$ the center of this circle. Let $K=AD \bigcup BI$ and $P= KF \bigcup BC$. If the point $Q$ is symmetric to $A$ with respect to $E$, prove that $PQ \perp CI$.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF**

*DRAWING:*

[image]

Okey, so the first thing that came in my mind when i read the text is to write that because $BC>AB$, $\angle BAC > \angle ACB$.

$AD,BE,CF$ are the bisectors of the angles of the triangle. We know that the center of a inscribed circle is the intersections of the bisectors.

Then, i don't understand the intersections. In my drawing $BI$ intersects $AD$ in $I$ which means that $I$ is the same as $K$. The same thing for $P= KF \bigcup BC$.

Is there my drawing wrong or the way i see the intersectons wrong? Hope one of you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your drawing looks wrong: $D,E,F$ are supposed to be the contact points of the inscribed circle, but you seem to have just drawn them at the midpoints of the sides of the triangle. (I don't understand how you decided where to put $I$.)

Comment: @Lynn $AD,BE,CF$ are the bisectors of the angles of the triangle. We know that the center of a inscribed circle is the intersections of the bisectors.

Comment: @Lynn I understand that i didnt really made the drawing clearly. I didnt draw the circle because it would just make the drawing harder to understand.

Comment: OK, that makes sense! I wrote an answer, but please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\underline{\bf{\color{red}{Note}}}$:$\space$
We provide below an answer/proof. But we have a request. Before going through this answer, you need to finish the conversation you have started with @Lynn to clear your doubts about the geometrical configuration.

To facilitate our proof, we added the line segments $DF$to the diagram that portraits the scenario describe in OP’s problem statement. For brevity, we let $\measuredangle ABC=2\beta$, $\measuredangle BCA=2\omega$, and $\measuredangle FKA=\alpha$.

From the properties of the incircle of a triangle, we know that $IB$ and $IC$ are the angle bisectors of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle BCA$ respectively and these lead to,
$$\measuredangle ABI=\measuredangle IBC=\beta \quad\text{and}\tag{1a}$$
$$\measuredangle BCI=\measuredangle ICA=\omega. \tag{1b}$$

We can also deduce that,
$$ID=IE=IF=r, \tag{1c}$$
$$AE=AF,\tag{1d}$$
$$BD-BF, \quad\text{and}\tag{1e}$$
$$CD=CE.\tag{1f}$$

Because of (1a) and (1e), according to SAS congruence rule, the triangle pair $BDK$ and $BKF$ are congruent. So, we have,
$$KD=KF \quad\text{and}\tag{2a}$$
$$\measuredangle BDK=\measuredangle KFB. \tag{2b}$$

Since both angle pairs ($\angle BDK,\space\angle KDP$) and ($\angle KFB,\space\angle AFK$), it follows from (2b) that,
$$\measuredangle KDP=\measuredangle AFK. \tag{3}$$

Furthermore, since $\angle FKA$ and $\angle PKD$ are opposite angles, we shall write,
$$\measuredangle FKA=\measuredangle PKD=\alpha. \tag{4}$$

Using (2b), (3), and (4), and quoting ASA congruence rule, we can state that the triangle pair $FKA$ and $PKD$ are congruent. Hence, we have,
$$AF=DP. \tag{5}$$

It is given that $AE=EC$. Using (1d) and (5), we can infer that,
$$EC=DP.\tag{6}$$

We can use (1f) and (6) to show that, $CP=CQ$, which makes the $\triangle PCQ$ isosceles. Since $CI$ is the angle bisector of the apex angle of the isosceles tringle $PCQ$, it is perpendicular to the base $PQ$ of the said triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You found the incenter by drawing and intersecting the bisectors, which is good, but you incorrectly took e.g. the point where the bisector through $A$ intersects $BC$ and called that $D$.

However, $D$ is supposed to be the point where *the inscribed circle contacts* $BC$, and in practice these are not going to be the same.

In this diagram I took from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngleBisector.html you can see $T_1$ is *not* the point where the inscribed circle touches the right side $A_2A_3$:

[image]

I tried adding an inscribed circle to your drawing and showing how the real $D,E,F$ will differ from the points you called $D,E,F$.

[image]

I encourage you to make a more precise drawing — $BE$ looks pretty off in particular — to convince yourself that this error does not merely result from artistic imprecision.

Here is a sketch in GeoGebra that includes $K$, $P$, and $Q$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand that i did some not really corect drawing. But what about the point $K and P$. How he reprezent them on the drawing?

Comment: @IonelaBuciu I added a drawing I made in GeoGebra.

Comment: I dont understand anything now. Should not $B,I,E$ be collinear?

Comment: @IonelaBuciu What makes you think they should be?